# is it possible to get firebase dynamic links analytics with REST API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm able to create a dynamic link through API request in jquery but to get data back I couldn't find any documentation on it. please advise..

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't possible initially, but recently the Dynamic Links analytics API has launched, take a look at the docs here: analytics api docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics#rest_api

Comment: This explains how you can get analytic details for a single short link? Where does it say how we can see an overview of links we created?